# Rethrowing exceptions in tasks c# without wait

Tags: c#, exception, task

I have a GUI application, in which I want to run something in a task, so it will not hold the UI. I want un unhandled exception in the task to be propogated to the application level exception handler.
However:

1. If I just throw an exception in the task it will not reach app level
   exceptions unless I use wait/await
2. Async/Await - I call the method from a UI constructor, so I can't use async/await there, since I need to continue with the consturction. I just want to run the task and forget.

I was thinking about using dispatcher.invoke, what do you think?

```
public MainWindow()
{
        InitializeComponent();

        MyMethodAsync();

        InitializeA();
        IntiializeB();
}

private void MyMethodAsync()
{
     Task t = Task.Run(() =>
     {
          //Do some stuff
          throw new Exception("Throwing some unexpected exception");
     }).ContinueWith(MyContinueWith);
}

private void MyContinueWith(Task task)
{
    if (task.IsFaulted && task.Exception != null)
    {
         dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
         {
            throw task.Exception;
         }), null);
    }
}
```

Comment: By convention methods that have a suffix of "Async" are normally methods which return a task that has already been started. With the async/await keywords this is handled somewhat automatically to the caller it doesn't really matter the implementation.

Comment: @skippy: `await` doesn't block your UI. It sounds like `await` has exactly the behavior you're wanting.

Comment: Why are you using `Task.ContinueWith`? It really isn't recommended, you should use C#5 `await` instead. The debugging potential alone makes it insane to use `Task.continueWith`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. The reason that I don't want to use await, is that I want to use MyMethodAsync, in a constructor that run on UI thread. So I don't to wait and hold the construction of my window. (I cannot make a constructor to be async)

Comment: I've edited the question with this comment

Comment: How about `async void`? AFAIK, it rethrow unhandled exceptions in original `SynchronizationContext`.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways I can think of. First, is register to [`TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception(v=vs.110).aspx) event and log whatever you need there:

```
private void MyMethodAsync()
{
    // Note you should probably register only once, so this may not fit here.
    TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (s, e) => GlobalLogger.Log(e);
    Task t = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Do some staff
    }).ContinueWith(MyContinueWith);
}
```

The better option which for some reason you don't want to use, is to actually await the operation and wrap it in a `try-catch`:

```
private async Task MyMethodAsync()
{
    try
    {
       await Task.Run(() =>
       {
          // Do some staff
       });
       InvokeContinuation();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Log.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Yuval, as I commented before the problem that I have with -await- is is that I want to use MyMethodAsync in a UI constructor, and I don't want to hold the constructor actions with await, I just want to run and forget.

Comment: @skippy Then go with the first option.

Comment: I've checked the first option, but it doesn't seem to help too. It will go to the event only when the task is collected by GC ( and I don't know when it will happen, it doesn't get to the handler in my example unless I call GC.Collect). I did notice now that when it is GC then the exception will be thrown, and reach my application level exception handler, which is good, but still I want to get there when the exception happens and not sometime depended on GC

Comment: @skippy Then you'll need to either synchronously or asynchronously wait.

Comment: Synchronously - I can't since it will hold my UI, and asynchronously ...? how do I do that (whithout getting back to the same problem)

Answer (score 0):

Do realize that by calling Task.Run you are generally spawning a new thread which is not likely what you want most of the time. Creating new threads makes sense in some instances where you are doing CPU bound work and in those cases you'll want to consider leveraging other [Parallel computation libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the most out of it. Instead if your work is I/O bound you should be able to use asynchronous calls all the way down.

In order to wait for the result of a async method call or an exception bubbled up to the call point you can always tack on a call to ContinueWith to the a task that is returned by the async method. If you are handling both the result and any possible exceptions then async/await semantics work nice. Note however that the code that executes in these continuations may not execute in the same thread as the original thread by default.